# Interpolation in texture3D in OpenGL ES 3.0 on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures, texture-mapping

I am passing a GL_TEXTURE_3D to the fragment shader in an iOS application. I am using minification and magnification filters as GL_LINEAR for this texture. However, the resulting texture rendered in the app has blocks instead of having a smooth transition of colors, which implies that it is using GL_NEAREST interpolation.
Here are the screenshots of the expected vs received output image
[image: expected output]
[image: output received]

PS: If I use a 2D texture instead, pass in the 3D texture as a flattened 2D texture and do the interpolation manually in the shader, it works all fine and I get the expected output.

Here is the code for setting up `GL_LINEAR`:

```
GLenum target, minificationFilter, magnificationFilter;
target = GL_TEXTURE_3D;
minificationFilter = GL_LINEAR;
magnificationFilter = GL_LINEAR;
glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, minificationFilter);
glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, magnificationFilter);
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you set up GL_LINEAR?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman: I edited the post to include the code. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Those blocks are quite large. Could it be texture quantisation? How are you uploading the texture?

Comment: I doubt that the blocks are big due to texture quantization. The 3D texture size is 17x17x17 and it is being displayed in a glkView of size 300 x 225 - I think this is the reason for the blocks being big. Since I am displaying only a slice of the 3D texture, you will notice there are 17x17 blocks.

Comment: I am uploading the texture by putting the data from `NSArray` into a `GLfloat *texels` and then uploading these texels into a texture using `glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA32F,
                     17, 17, 17,
                     0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, texels);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear filtering of textures with internal format `GL_RGBA32F` is not supported in ES 3.0.

You can see which formats support linear filtering in table 3.13 of the ES 3.0 spec document, on pages 130-132. The last column, with header "Texture-filterable", indicates which formats support filtering. `RGBA32F` does not have a checkmark in that column.

If you need linear filtering for float textures, you're limited to 16-bit component floats. `RGBA16F` in the same table has the checkmark in the last column.

This limitation is still in place in the latest ES 3.2 spec.

There is an extension to lift this limitation: [OES_texture_float_linear](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float_linear.txt). However, this extension is not listed under the [supported extensions on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html).

Comment: Switching from `RGBA32F` to `RGBA16F` seemed to have done the trick for me. Thanks for the detailed explanation and pointing out the reference in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch from the single precision float format `GL_RGBA32F` to the half-float format `GL_RGBA16F` then `GL_LINEAR` magnification works fine.

I can't find any documentation to suggest why this shouldn't work, and the only limitation on single precision float textures seems to be when used as render targets, so I guess this is a bug to be filed under "`GL_RGBA32F` ignores `GL_LINEAR` magnification on iOS 9".

If it genuinely *is* a bug, then be understanding - I imagine an `OpenGLES 3` implementation to be one of the largest, most awful switch-statement-driven pieces of code that one could possibly have the misfortune to work on. If you consider that whatever glamour the job might have entailed previously has since been sucked out by the release of the faster, sexier and legacy-free [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/) then you're probably talking about a very unloved codebase, maintained by some very unhappy people. *You're lucky flat shaded triangles even work*.

p.s. when using `GL_TEXTURE_3D` don't forget to clamp in the *third* coordinate (`GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R`)

p.p.s test this on a device. neither `GL_RGBA32F` nor `GL_RGBA16F` seem to work with `GL_LINEAR` on the simulator

Comment: I will try out GL_RGBA16F and get back to you.

PS - I am clamping the third coordinate :) and I am testing it on a device. I agree that the simulator is not very reliable.

Comment: `GL_RGBA16F` instead of `GL_RGBA32F` works all fine with GL_LINEAR. Thanks!